# How to build Xcode project from the command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

I've tried reading the [Xcode Tools documentation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) Apple provides, so that I can use the Terminal to build a `.app` file and run the resulting app on the Simulator. Essentially what I want to do is do the same thing as `Cmd` + `R` does on Xcode.

So far I've attempted to build my `.xcodeproj` like this:

```
xcodebuild -configuration Debug build
```

However, when I install & run it on the Simulator I get an app w/ a black screen:

```
// Boot device
xcrun simctl boot "iPhone 7" 
// Install app
xcrun simctl install "iPhone 7" "/Users/.../MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app"
// Open simulator
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
// Launch app using its bundle id
xcrun simctl launch booted "com.example.apps.MyApp"
```

Not to mention the `xcrun simctl launch booted "com.example.apps.MyApp"` line never terminates and on the Simulator it keeps trying to open and reopen the app, but the app only ever shows a black screen.

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong with the building of the`.xcodeproj` that would be great!

Comment: This command "xcodebuild -configuration Debug build" broke my Xcode settings.

Answer (score 53):

After having a working configuration in Xcode, open a shell and navigate to the directory, where your `<NAME>.xcodeproj` resides.

After running:

```
xcodebuild -list -project <NAME>.xcodeproj/
```

you see a list of *Schemes*.

Copy the desired scheme name and run:

```
xcodebuild -workspace <WORKSPACE NAME> -scheme <SCHEME NAME> build
```

You can install [ios-deploy][1] i.e. via:

```
npm install -g ios-deploy
```

Copy the app path from the end of the *xcodebuild* output and run:

```
ios-deploy --debug --bundle <APP PATH>
```

Now the app should be launched on i.e. a connected device.
[1]: https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy

Answer (score 0):

@Tsunamis' answer is wonderful.

Also, if your project has a package, that uses some specific iOS libraries like `UIKit`, and you are having errors about UI controls not found, you can compile the package using this command line:

`` xcodebuild -scheme <package -sdk "`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`" -target x86_64-apple-ios14.0-simulator ``