# Is it possible to install a ".app" build file to an iPad from within Xcode, without loading the actual project file?

Tags: ios, xcode, file-transfer

Without actually loading my `.xcodeproj` into Xcode, is it possible, from the Xcode app, to start an app install to my iPad using the `.app` file only, which was generated in an earlier build?

This is my last line of inquiry... I'm just looking at potential options because I don't have a paid developer account (yet) and might try to use Teamviewer to log into the remote client Mac to install via Xcode, but do not wish to reveal my project file/code on the remote machine. Installing from within Xcode purely using the `.app` file would solve my problem, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work out a way to do it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681264/how-to-build-xcode-project-from-the-command-line), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984727/how-to-get-app-file-of-a-xcode-application), and [this](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/issues/346). You will need the XCode command line tools, which come as part of the App Store XCode install, or you can get the command line tools only from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html).

First up, download and install [npm](https://nodejs.org/en/). Then install `ios-deploy` from the terminal,

```
sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm --allow-root
```

If you need to build from the command line, make sure you have a working XCode project which builds as you want, open a terminal and go to the directory with your `.xcodeproj` inside, then type:

```
xcodebuild -list -project <NAME>.xcodeproj/
xcodebuild -scheme <SCHEME NAME> build
```

Then, or if you've already built in XCode and just want to deploy your `.app` file to the iOS device, type:

```
ios-deploy debug --bundle <APP PATH>
```

You can change `debug` to `release`, or either way it will use whatever you set your XCode build configuration to be I think. The `<APP PATH>` location depends on your XCode install, but the most recent location (I think) is

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/Build/Products/Deployment/
```

This will install your `.app` onto the iOS device from the command line, and you don't need to load XCode up, or expose your source files. Just requires the `.app` file. For me, this is a potentially useful way to install an app remotely on a client's device without the need for a paid developer account.