# I am having a problem building my app locally on my Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode12.5

I updated macOS to Big Sur and Xcode to 12.5 and I am trying to build my app locally. Build Succeeded but when it come to run the simulator I have an error Executable not found see the below image.

Note: this is a quick cocos2d generated project.

Archiving and building on test flight is working fine.

[image]

I tried to delete my derived data and all my caches and rebuild again I still have the same problem.

I also go to Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes, and I deleted all the current scheme and autocreate schemes again it didn't work still same issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you clean the project? Did you delete Derived Data?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez yes i deleted my derived data and even all my caches and tried to rebuild same issue.

Comment: When you say "deleted all my chances" do you mean Clean/Deep Clean of the project? If not - please do it. Clean is Command-Shift-K and deep clean is Command-Option-Shift-K.

Comment: i can't perform a deep clean i went to product -> then i press on the option key then i can't press on clean build folder any idea...

Comment: This isn't a solution so I'm just adding it here. Xcode has a bug where sometimes the filesystem and its internal file database get out of sync. You may be able to figure out what is going on by opening the shell, changing directory to your project files, finding the name of your xcodeproj directory, running "xcodebuild -list -project ./Whatever.xcodeproj", then find the Scheme you are trying to use, and then run "xcodebuild -scheme SchemeName build". See this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681264/how-to-build-xcode-project-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is simply go to Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes.. and delete the current scheme and create a new one. With that it worked again

Comment: so far i deleted all my current schemes then i autocreate schemes again then rebuild  same issue Execute not found!

Comment: Any solution for this